# ¿Cómo pasar parámetro por URL en LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel

¿Cómo podría pasar un parámetro junto a la ruta para que después dependiendo del parámetro pueda realizar una cosa u otra? Tengo una página llamada "preguntas" donde debería llegar el parámetro llamado "asignatura" donde podría llegar por ejemplo el valor "cienciasnaturales", ó "historia", etc.

```
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/preguntas') }}">
        Ciencias Naturales
    </a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/preguntas') }}">
        Historia
    </a>
```

¿Y en la ruta como la adaptamos para que tome ese parámetro "asignatura"?

```
Route::get('/preguntas', function () {
    return view('preguntas');
});
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Algo así creo que te puede servir:

Links:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/preguntas/cienciasnaturales') }}">
    Ciencias Naturales
</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/preguntas/historia') }}">
    Historia
</a>
```

Ruta:

```
Route::get('/preguntas/{asignatura}', function ($asignatura) {
    return view('preguntas', [
        'asignatura' => $asignatura
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Los parámetros en Laravel se pasan del modo siguiente

```
Route::get('/preguntas/{asignatura}', function($asignatura){
    //aquí las acciones que vas a realizar
});
```

- Es decir, después de indicar la URI, pasas entre *llaves* el nombre de la variable; en este caso `asignatura`
- Posterior, si no usas por ejemplo ningún controlador, pasas esa misma variable a la función anónima para poder disponer de ella y su valor y utilizarla

Puedes establecer como opcional el parámetro, agregando este símbolo: `?` justo después de escribir dicho valor en la ruta, así

```
'/preguntas/{asignatura?}'
```

Además al pasar dicho parámetro, en este caso deberás otorgarle un valor pudiendo quedar así:

```
Route::get('/preguntas/{asignatura?}', function($asignatura = "biología"){
    //aquí las acciones que vas a realizar
});
```

Referencias:

- [Route params](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters)